# $\mathit{Var}_{x,y} ( f(x,y) ) \le \mathit{Var}_{x}(f(x,x))$ ? (uniform distribution)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $x$ and $y$ are sampled from a uniform probability distribution $[a,b] \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: [a,b]\times [a,b]  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then is true that $\mathit{Var}_{x,y} ( f(x,y) ) \le \mathit{Var}_{x}(f(x,x))$ ?

For example, if $[a,b]=[0,1]$, I'd like to understand if it's true that:

$\left( \int_0^1 dx \int_0^1 dy\, f^2(x,y)\right) - \left(\int_0^1 dx \int_0^1 dy\, f(x,y)\right)^2 \le \left( \int_0^1 dx\, f^2(x,x)\right) - \left(\int_0^1 dx\,  f(x,x)\right)^2$

Comment: Are X and Y independent variables?

Comment: No, consider $$f(x,y) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \text{ if } x=y\\ xy & \text{ otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.,$$ then $Var_x\left(f(x,x)\right) \leq Var_{x,y}\left(f(x,y)\right).$ If you want a continuous function, consider $f(x,y) = x -y$.